# When the function $y(x)=f(x)^{g(x)}$ is defined?

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

Suppose we have the function $y(x)=f(x)^{g(x)}$. should $f(x)>0$ in order to $y(x)$ being defined? and why?

For example if we have $y=(\sin x)^x$ what happens when $x\in(-1,0)$ or $x\in(\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2})$ ?

I am confused.

Comment: You can get complex numbers when taking real exponents of negative numbers. e.g. $(-1)^{\pi} = e^{i\pi^2}$ which is a complex number. Also the result may admit multiple values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If working strictly in the reals:
$$f^g=e^{g\ln f}$$
and then we see that $f(x)>0$ is necessary for the exponentiation to be defined *in any interval larger than isolated points* ($(-1)^x$ is only defined at integral $\mathbb Z$ for example).

If complex numbers are allowed, such a restriction disappears, though the result may be multivalued.

Comment: Oh I got it. but what happens if we plug in $x=-1$ in the function $x^{(x^2)}$ we get $(-1)^{(-1)^2}$ and it is equal to $-1$. what is wrong for this negative value of $x$ that we say function is undefined?

Comment: Or maybe I misunderstood. what about this scenario: $y=(-x^2)^{x}$ is always undefined. am I right? (I am talking about real numbers)

Comment: @soheil $(-1)^x$ stays in the reals precisely when $x$ is an integer. I am referring to the ability to extend this definedness at a point to an interval of the real line - not possible within the reals.

Comment: Hmm if we have $a^b$ ($a$ is a number which is output of $f$ and $b$ output of $g$) then for $a\in(t,0)$ (where $t<0$ ) because it is is possible that $a^b$ be complex- number we say it is undefined. Am I right?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what is integral at the point. Is it something non-elementary in math?

Comment: @soheil It's elementary, really. Being an _integer_.

Comment: Ohh I thought it is something about integration! thank you I got it.

Comment: Thank you very much. it is tricky you factored out $(-1)$ from the negative number and analyzed $(-1)^x$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that we're restricting ourselves to the reals:

It is not quite necessary to have $f(x) > 0$, but close. In particular:

1. If $g(x) \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$ for all $x$, then $f(x)^{g(x)} = f(x)$ is well-defined, regardless of what $f(x)$ is.
2. If $g(x) \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $x$, then $f(x)^{g(x)}$ is well-defined unless there is $x$ such that $f(x) = g(x) = 0$.
3. These are essentially the only exceptions, for the reason that the other answer gives.